# why it doesnt keep track of the score

Tags: python

so i started learning python yesterday (0 programming background) and i cant figure out why my code doesnt keep track of the score

```
import random

def main(score):

    choice = int(input("put your number here \n"))

    number = random.randint(0,5)

    if (choice < number):
        print("sorry you missed, guess was too low")
    elif choice > number:
        print("sorry you missed guess was too high")
    elif choice == number:
        print("congratz u won\n")
        score += 1

global score
score = 0

while True:

    main(score)
    print("your score is " + str(score))
    player_input = input("wanna continue? press ""enter"" else type ""exit"" 
\n")
    if player_input == "exit":
        exit()
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Question is maybe too vague. What do you mean by 'keep track' ? Also, coding seems really bad : don't use global. Isn't the while loop infinite ?

Comment: @Mike give him some slack if he started yesterday. And the loop does exit via the `exit()` function.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be rude, was just trying to understand the question to help. Maybe my sentence is badly written

Comment: Appreciate your try as a beginner, first of all you can just refer in google how to use global variables, also I think no need to pass that score parameter in main function if you are using global variable.

Comment: well if run the code it works fine but the score variable doesnt increment if i "win" its still 0 and i cant find the logical error i made

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `global score` in your `main` function, **not** in the top-level script.

I would point out that it is considered bad practise in python to use `global` at all and it is better to `return score` and use `score = main(score)` but I'll let you off the hook if you just started.

For future reference, there are better places for asking beginner level questions (such as [reddit.com/r/learnpython](http://reddit.com/r/learnpython)).